# MySQL: Unable to import all table in SQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_postmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `post_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4601843 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC `PAGE_COMPRESSED`=1
```

**Error**

> MySQL said: Documentation #1064 - You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near '`PAGE_COMPRESSED`=1' at line 6

Comment: Well, just remove `PAGE_COMPRESSED=1` if your version of MySQL doesn't support it.

Comment: Hit me but don't you just need to remove the ` (ticks) to make it work? Just in case the previous comment isn't your prefered solution.